How to log setof row passed as rpc function in postgres
So In production, my rpc function isn't working correctly.
Basically I have this code
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.update_service_users(workspace_id_value uuid, updated_users users_service_insertion_data[])
 RETURNS void
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    -- Create a temporary table for updated_users
    CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_updated_users ON COMMIT DROP AS
    SELECT * FROM unnest(updated_users);

    -- Deactivate users not in updated_users
    UPDATE users_list AS s 
    SET user_state = 'deactivated'::user_state 
    WHERE workspace_id = workspace_id_value 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM temp_updated_users u
        WHERE u.id = s.account_id
        AND u.service_name = s.service_name
    );

    -- Insert or update users from updated_users
    INSERT INTO users_list 
        (
            account_id, 
            name, 
            email, 
            workspace_id, 
            user_state, 
            outside_organisation, 
            company_user_id,
            service_name,
            service_role
        )
    SELECT 
        u.id,
        u.name, 
        NULLIF(u.email, ''),
        workspace_id_value, 
        u.type, 
        COALESCE(u.outside_organisation, NULL), 
        cu.id,
        u.service_name,
        u.service_role
    FROM temp_updated_users u
    LEFT JOIN company_users AS cu ON cu.email = u.email
    ON CONFLICT (account_id, service_name) DO UPDATE 
    SET 
        name = EXCLUDED.name,
        email = EXCLUDED.email,
        account_id = EXCLUDED.account_id, 
        user_state = EXCLUDED.user_state,
        service_role = EXCLUDED.service_role;
        
    RETURN;
END;
$function$
;

Here, I pass the data the updated data as updated_users and if

The data exists in the new updated_users and not in the db, I mark it as deactivated user
Else, I insert/update the values (the latest value returned by service).

Now for some reason, for some user email is coming out to be null,
Is there a way to log what data is being passed to update_service_users or how to debug it. (let's say I can look at the data being sent from the API, instead only at Postgres level).
I am using supabase, postgres

You can log a messaging using raise log and it will appear in your Supabase dashboard under the Postgres logs.
